# HTTP POST (IOS)

Tags: ios, http, post

I need to do an HTTP POST for a page that simply returns a literal (which can be "OK" or "ERROR") I have a web tutorial that shows how to do this and it returns a JSON, I follow the tutorial and it works perfectly .
My problem is exactly there ... it returns a JSON and what my site returns is not a JSON but a simple literal ..
How do I get this literal that the site is returning ... I've tried several changes in the code below but without success.

```
let parameters = ["username": "@kilo_loco", "tweet": "HelloWorld"]

guard let url = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/ola.php") else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
//request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
request.httpBody = httpBody

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print ("*******")
        print(response)
    }

    //print(data as Any)

    if let data = data {
        print("** TESTE **")
       print(data)
        //do {
          //  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            //print(json)
        //} catch {
          //  print(error)
       // }
    }

}.resume()
```

The Last "Print (data) returns the size in bytes and not the contents of the literal ..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parse Data to JSON Object, I think you have that code almos there but commented

```
        do {
            let json:AnyObject? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json{
                 print(parseJSON)
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hello Reinier.. no, the code is commented because what my site return is not a JSON but a single literal.

Comment: @Eduardo try with if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { debugPrint(string)} and let me know what prints

Comment: Hy.. Reiner I did what you sugeste (if let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {print(string)}) and there was no additional results..

Comment: Here what was printed : *******
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x79fd9e50> { URL: http://digiplaypedidos.com/ola.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 130;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 30 Jul 2017 15:23:02 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "X-App-Status" = 1;
    "X-Cache-Status" = BYPASS;
    "X-Domain-Checked" = FALSE;
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-Provisioner-Version" = "v3.3.7-181116";
} }
** TESTE **
12 bytes

Comment: I will review it is getting status 200 so it's fine

Comment: I also checked the variable "string" and it is nil

Comment: I made some test and realized that if the return is in JSON format your command Works.

Comment: @Eduardo so, problem solved then? can you accept my answer?

Comment: No. the problem was not solved. I still don't know how to get the site return when it is not a JSON.